# Commerce tag - synonym of economy?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [commerce](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) is applied to 2 questions, both of which also have [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy). It doesn't seem to add anything extra to these 2 questions, and I don't anticipate it being needed for future questions.

I'd like to hear both sides of the discussion on whether commerce should be removed or merged with economy.

Comment: They do seem like good synonym candidates. Are there any cases where one of them would apply to a question and another not? That seems to me like a good synonym test...

Comment: @TimB I see commerce as a sub-tag of economy, but without adding enough to make it worthwhile. My own suggestion would be to just remove the commerce tag - maybe I'll add that as an answer to see how the votes go.

Comment: Does commerce have non-economic aspects?  It seems like it could overlap with travel, culture, and politics.  Should a question about establishing trade routes get "commerce" even though it's mainly asking about travel logistics?

Answer (score 12):

**The [commerce](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) tag is not useful and should be removed.** It is slightly more specific than [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) without adding enough to justify its use. The economy tag is a useful distinction applied to several questions. The commerce tag seems more like a tag applied for the sake of it, just to make up the numbers.

It was recently used to replace the [money](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) tag, which I agree was redundant. However, I think [commerce](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) is redundant too, and it would be better to discard both money and commerce in favour of just having [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy).

Comment: A "currency" or maybe even "coinage" tag on the other hand might be useful.

Comment: @TimB last night I deleted a "money" tag from (IIRC) two questions, because it was being used as a synonym of economy.  I could see value in a "currency" or "coinage" tag, but we'll need to make the distinction clear.  (It would need a good wiki, for starters.)

Comment: Should commerce not be a synonym, obviously some people think of it before economy.

Comment: @DonyorM it hasn't yet been used in place of economy - its only instances were in addition to the economy tag (that is, questions tagged with economy and commerce)

Comment: Coinage could definitely be useful at some point.  This early on I don't know that we have had any questions specifically regarding currency though.  Commerce and Economy have definitely been used the same thus far.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [commerce](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce) should become a synonym of [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy). It means almost the same thing, close enough to mean the same thing. People have used it, even though they use it in conjunction with economy. If it is a synonym, you can't use it twice, but it will allow people who are unfamiliar with the terms to use it instead of economy.